# A graph database with embedded code in node

Tags: database, graph, janusgraph

Does anyone know if there is any graph database platform, or system, in which one could embed a code in a node? For example, can one embed codes in a node in JanusGraph?

Comment: is this code arbitrary ?

Comment: That's a fair question--but not here.  This site is not about answering "Is there any library that does X" type questions.  Answers here are earned by having done a certain amount of due dillegence to find (by other means) and actually try solutions.

Comment: In the title, you wrote "embedded code", but in the question, "embed a code". Are you asking about embedding source code to be executed or a classification code that has meaning to your application?

Answer (score 1):

In JanusGraph, you can store code as a `String` for a vertex property, then use Groovy to evaluate and execute the code during your traversal. There isn't a built-in Gremlin step to do this, so you'd have to use a [lambda step](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#a-note-on-lambdas) (Groovy closure).

Comment: I posted an example on [gremlin-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?source=mog&gl=us#!topic/gremlin-users/EdDFS8SCnHU)

Answer (score 0):

Yea you can try [LevelGraph](https://github.com/levelgraph/levelgraph). LevelGraph is a Graph Database. Unlike many other graph database, LevelGraph is built on the uber-fast key-value store LevelDB through the powerful LevelUp library. You can use it inside your node.js application or in any IndexedDB-powered Browser.